# Is this a case for Multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

Good day to you all!

I have seen lots of questions here on turning retrieved mySQL data into PHP arrays...but I am green with PHP and cannot seem to make the leap to my own coding.  My project is to create a gallery of downloads (images, pdfs, zip files) in Wordpress.  This involves creating a gallery of placeholder images, then adding the actual files to a download manager plugin.  The plugin creates an entry for each file in the wp_posts table with a post_type of 'download' and a unique download id in the guid field.  So I THINK the code needs to:

1. Create an array of all file names (and IDs?) of post_type 'download'
2. Check if the currently viewed gallery image (post_type 'attachment') is also post_type 'download' by seeking the post_title in the array above
3. If yes, create a 'Download' link on the fly by retrieving the corresponding ID from the guid field

I have been able to successfully list the titles in one array and the IDs in one array, but I can't find the right ID when I put it into the link address.

I have posted this to the plugin's author on WP forums, but it's been days with no reply.  How can this be done?  Do I need a multidimensional array?

I thank you all for your help in the past and hopefully on this issue too.

Comment: This is just a job spec - StackOverflow questions need to be specific and the bottom line is that you need to have made an attempt at this yourself.  Post questions containing code about the specific issues you are coming up against as you work through your task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but:

```
// create a list of post_titles with corresponding guids
$sql= "SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'download'";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
$downloads = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

// now you can loop through these downloads
foreach ($downloads as $download){
    if ($download['post_title'] == this_image_post_title){
        // create the link you want with $download['guid']
    }
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help Cubis!  Just right!  Not sure why your answer got a downvote.  But again, thanks for your time.